# Double pointer for argv

Tags: c, arrays, unix, parameters, startup

I am trying to create argv for a new process(trying to use execvp), and I checked the execvp manual page which says it needs char *const argv[].

I assume this is an pointer to array of char pointers. So is it possible to pass double pointer of char to this argument?

Basically, what I am trying to do is as following
(argvcounter is number of arguments. ex) cat a -> argvcount = 2)

```
int argvcount;
char **argv;
...
argv = malloc(sizeof(char*)*(argvcount+1));
for (int i = 0; i<argvcount; i++){
    argv[i] = some char pointer;
}
argv[-1] = NULL;
```

I am not sure about the last line either. I am setting last element to NULL since the last element of array of arguments have to be NULL.

Is it possible to pass this argv to execvp?

Thank you.

Comment: The last line should be `argv[argvcount] = NULL;`

Comment: Yes, you should be able to pass a `char **`.

Comment: @WeatherVane is there any difference from argv[-1]?

Comment: `argv[-1]` is *undefined behaviour* indexing outside the bounds of an array. You have allocated memory for `(argvcount+1)` elements, which can be indexed from `0` to `argvcount`.

Comment: In Python, -1 can be used to index the last element, but in C it's invalid. Different languages are different.

Comment: As an aside, it's customary to call the counter `argc`, not `argvcount`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the C Standard (5.1.2.2.1 Program startup, p.#2)

```
— argv[argc] shall be a null pointer
```

So you have to write

```
argv[argvcount] = NULL;
```

This statement

```
argv[-1] = NULL;
```

does not make sense and results in undefined behavior.

> I assume this is an pointer to array of char pointers. So is it
>   possible to pass double pointer of char to this argument?

An array designater with rare exceptions is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element.

So if for example you have an array like this

```
char * argv[argvcount];
```

then passed to a function it is converted to pointer to its first element and has type `char **`.

On the other hand, these function declarations

```
void f( char *a[] );
```

and

```
void f( char **a );
```

are equivalent because the compiler adjusts the type of a parameter declared as an arrray to the type of pointer to an object of the array element type.

Answer (score 1):

> it needs `char *const argv[]`. I assume this is an pointer to array of char pointers.

No, it is an array of `char* const` pointers. It might help reading these declarations from right to left:

- `[]` An array (of unknown size)...
- `argv` ...named argv...
- `const` ... of const...
- `*` ...pointers...
- `char` ...to char.

In plain English: An array (of unknown size) named argv, of read-only pointers to character.

> So is it possible to pass double pointer of char to this argument?

Please note the subtle difference between arguments and parameters. Parameter referring to the variable in the function declaration, argument referring to the things you pass to the function on the caller side. It matters here.

Because a function taking a parameter of type `char *const argv[]`, will have that parameter silently "adjusted" by the compiler into a pointer to the first element (sometimes called "array decay"). This is why we don't have to specify the array size - it will "decay" no matter the array size.

The first element is a `char*const` and a pointer to such an element is of type `char*const*`, so that's the type that the function will expect. A pointer to a const pointer to char - at the second level of indirection, the pointer itself cannot be modified.

As it happens, `char**` is a type that may be implicitly converted to `char*const*`, because the latter is a "qualified" version of the former - it is the same type but with "more `const` in the right places". Generally, any `type*` can be converted to `type*const`.

Had the parameter been `const char* argv[]`, it wouldn't have been possible to use `char**`, because in that case the `const` belongs to the pointed-at type and not the pointer.

---

As already pointed out, note that `argv[-1] = NULL;` is nonsense, it should be `argv[argvcount] = NULL;`